# How do I get Ubuntu server 14.04 to display after installation on virtual box

Tags: 14.04, server

I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS into oracle Virtual Box, however after installation it says to remove cd from drive and continue to restart. I entered continue, it finished installing and confirmed the installation to be successful, however I do not get to see Ubuntu home page with logo and icons it remains a blank or black screen.

How do I get the software to be visible?

Answer (score 2):

If you press enter, you will see the login prompt. This is text mode.

The server versions of Ubuntu do not have a GUI to show "Icons" You need you follow these steps shown on the [Ubuntu ServerGUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI) wiki to get that setup